# Is it possible to use the multiclass classifier of aws to recognize the given place of the text?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, classification, amazon-sagemaker, multiclass-classification

I'm using AWS SageMaker, and i want to create something that, with a given text, it recognize the place of that description. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If there are no other classes besides the text that you would like your model to identify, you may not need a multiclass classifier.

You *could* train your own text detection model using **Amazon SageMaker**, and train using a dataset with labelled examples using the [Object Detection Algorithm](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/object-detection.html), but this becomes rather involved for a problem that has existing solutions available.

If the appearance of the text you're trying to detect is identical each time, your problem space gets reduced from trying to interpret variable text, to simply having to gather enough examples and perform object detection for the "pattern" your text forms visually. Note that if the text were to appear in different fonts or styles, that the generic object detection method would not interpret it dynamically, and an OCR-based solution would likely be necessary.

---

More broadly, for text identification in images on AWS, you have quite a few options:

**Amazon Rekognition** has a [`DetectText` method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/text-detection.html) that will enable you to easily find text within an image. If it's a small or simple phrase, with alphanumeric characters, this should work very well for your use case.

**Amazon Textract** will help you perform OCR (optical character recognition) while retaining the structure of the source. This is great for documents and tables, but doesn't sound like it may be applicable to your use case.

The **AWS marketplace** will also have hosted options available from third party vendors. One example of this for text region identification is [this one from RocketML](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/prodview-l7orjph2654zc).

There are also some great **open source tools** I'd recommend looking into: OpenCV for ascertaining the text bounding boxes, and Tesseract for OCR and text extraction. [This blog post](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/17/opencv-ocr-and-text-recognition-with-tesseract/) does a good job walking through the process of using them together.

Any of these will help to solve your problem of performing OCR/text identification on AWS, but the best choice comes down to what your current and future needs are, and how quickly you're looking to implement the feature.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear regarding the data that you have or the problem that you want to solve.

If you have a text that includes a place name in it (for example, "I visited Seattle and enjoyed the fish market"), you can use [Amazon Comprehend](https://aws.amazon.com/comprehend/) Name Entity Extraction (NEE) including places ("Seattle" in the above example)

```
{
    "Entities": [
        {
            "Score": 0.9857407212257385,
            "Type": "LOCATION",
            "Text": "Seattle",
            "BeginOffset": 10,
            "EndOffset": 17
        }
    ]
}
```

If the description is more general and you want to classify if the description is of a hotel, a restaurant, a theme park, a concert/show, or similar **types** of places, you can either use the Custom classification in Comprehend or the Neural Topic Model in SageMaker (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/ntm.html). You will need some examples of the classes and documents/sentences that are used for the model training.